# Not able to send mail from linux command

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, sendmail, ssmtp

I wan to send an email from a linux command. I installed in ubuntu ssmtp, then I configured it in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf:

```
root=mymail@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=mymail@gmail.com
AuthPass=xxxxxxxxx
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

then I tried to send the email like that:

```
ssmtp receiver_mail@gmail.com < msg.txt
```

But I got this error:

```
ssmtp: Authorization failed (535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t187sm393455wmt.25 - gsmtp)
```

then I tried with sendmail command:

```
 echo -n 'Subject: test\n\nTesting ssmtp' | sendmail -v receiver_mail@gmail.com
```

But I got the same error:

```
[<-] 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a22sm418259wmd.20 - gsmtp
[->] EHLO omar-X550LC
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
[->] EHLO omar-X550LC
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[->] b21hci5rYWxsZWwzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
[<-] 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[<-] 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a22sm418259wmd.20 - gsmtp
sendmail: Authorization failed (535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a22sm418259wmd.20 - gsmtp)
```

seems like that there's something wrong or missing in ssmtp config. Is there any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reading the support link it included in the error message?  In addition to the possibility that you're supplying the wrong password, it gives a few other possibilities:

> - Use an App Password: If you use 2-Step Verification, try signing in with an App Password.
> - Allow less secure apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you might need to allow less secure apps to access your account.
> - Make sure your mail app isn't set to check for new email too frequently. If your mail app checks for new messages more than once
>     every 10 minutes, the app’s access to your account could be blocked.